# Set administrator privilege for my C++ application in VS2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, administrator, privilege

I am currently working on Windows 7 porting of one of our Framework. It was successfully running in Windows-XP 64bit platform.
Now I am building all my projects in Windows 7 64-bit. But I couldn't find a correct method
to specify admin privilege ('Require Administrator') for my projects.

We have already ported these projects in to Windows 7 in VS2008. In VS2008 UAC permission can be directly set from
Project Settings->Linker->Manifest File->UAC Execution Level. But this property is not available in VS2005.

I tried to edit app.manifest file for the application by referring http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235591.aspx . It ask for converting the manifest file to resource file but I couldn't find a way to do the same. So the link didn't work for me.

How can I do the same using VS2005, please help.

Regards,
Nixon

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried manually edit manifest and add `requireAdministrator`? You can read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx for more details.